# Python - showing 'once' warnings again (resetting all warning registries)

Tags: python, warnings

is there a way to reset the `__warningregistry__` of all loaded functions at once?

I would like to force all warnings that are filtered with the 'once' filter to show again. I have found no way of doing this aside from calling `<func>.__globals__['__warningregistry__'].clear()` on every function that I have loaded (including those that are part of an imported module.)

So, what I want is something like a `warnings.clear()` function to do the following:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.warn('blah')
WARNING:root:blah ->UserWarning at ...
>>> warnings.warn('blah')
>>> warnings.clear()
>>> warnings.warn('blah')
WARNING:root:blah ->UserWarning at ...
```

And I want this `warnings.clear()` function to also clear **all warning registries**, not just the current name-space.

Is this already existent? Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, or using the module incorrectly?

Comment: Here is the Python bug tracking the issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue21724

Answer (score 6):

That functionality doesn't appear to exist in Python directly.

However, I needed similar functionality for my own libraries' unittests, and worked up a context manager that backs up the warning registry state for the entire process, clears it, and then restores it after the context is done.

It's a little too long to post here, but I've submitted it as a potential starting point for solving [python bug 21724](http://bugs.python.org/issue21724), so you should be able to download and use it directly from http://bugs.python.org/file40031/reset_warning_registry.py

Usage is as follows:

```
from reset_warning_registry import reset_warning_registry

with reset_warning_registry():
    ... do things with clear registry ...

# alternately, to just clear the warnings w/o restoring
reset_warning_registry().__enter__()
```

Comment: Nice, I've had need for this too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this functionality exists, at least not in 2.7.6.  I looked through the warnings.py and _warnings.c and I didn't find anything you could use to do this.

I was thinking perhaps you could wrap the module and override the `warn()` call to put globals()['__warningregistry__'] in a list, and add a new `clear()` function to loop it and reset the registry for all calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think that setting a filter to "always" can meet this need.

```
> cat warnme.py 
import warnings

for i in range(3):
    warnings.warn("oh noes!")

> python warnme.py 
warnme.py:4: UserWarning: oh noes!
warnings.warn("oh noes!")

> cat warnme2.py 
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("always")
for i in range(3):
    warnings.warn("oh noes!")

> python warnme2.py 
warnme2.py:5: UserWarning: oh noes!
warnings.warn("oh noes!")
warnme2.py:5: UserWarning: oh noes!
warnings.warn("oh noes!")
warnme2.py:5: UserWarning: oh noes!
warnings.warn("oh noes!")
```